# Metabase chart does not display on dashboard upon filtering, but displays when clicked on

Tags: filter, visualization, metabase

I've created some questions (charts) that display perfectly on their own. When added to the dashboard they also display perfectly. However, upon adding some filters on the dashboard and selecting the appropriate fields in each of the chart, once I activated the filter, many of these charts produced this error: "There was a problem displaying this chart".

However, clicking on and going into these charts individually showed them to be functioning perfectly, with the filtered results displaying correctly as well. So this means the filter works on an individual chart level, but not on the dashboard level.... can anyone provide some answers? Thank you!

P.S. I should also mention that upon filtering and clicking onto the charts with errors, for some reason the charts change in visuals (e.g. all of them were initially bar charts, upon dashboard-level filtering and clicking onto them, they became line charts instead... weird)